# Is it possible to insert on the same table on which you are applying an after update trigger? Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, database-trigger, auto-update

So I do have a problem of understanding here. I would really appreciate if you help to clear my confusion. 
So i have 2 tables table_1 and table_2 , where both the tables have the same columns as 'id' pk auto increment and 'name' varchar(20) . 
Lets say i already have an after insert trigger on table_1 where everything i insert something in table_1 it stores the same copy in table_2 as well. 
Now i wanted to apply an update trigger on the same table (table_1) to control if someone tries to modify the name in table_1 , it should take the name from table_2 and insert the correct name back to table_1.
I hope i explained it well. I will share the after update trigger i made which did not work. I would be more than happy if you help. Thank u

```
delimiter $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `Practice`.`table_1_after_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `table_1` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if  old.name != new.name  then
update table_1 
set name = table_2.name
where id = table_2.id;
end if;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: 1) Setting any value in AFTER UPDATE trigger makes no sense - the record is updated already. 2) You cannot update the table which the trigger is defined on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `Practice`.`table_1_BEFORE_UPDATE` 
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON `table_1` 
FOR EACH ROW
set NEW.name = OLD.name;
```